# About genderless breeding

Tags: pokemon-series

Pokemon like Staryu, Starmie, Klinklang, Rotom, etc, can only breed with Dittos?

For example, Rotom, is listed in the amorphus egg group according to http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/479.shtml.
I have tried to breed it with some pokemons of the same group and the response was always negative, so i had to use a Ditto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Genderless pokemon are only capable of breeding with Ditto (if they can breed at all).

http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_breeding

> How to breed
>
> Pokémon can be bred by leaving two compatible Pokémon at the Pokémon
>   Day Care in Generation II and beyond, located on Route 34 in Johto,
>   Route 117 in Hoenn, Four Island in the Sevii Islands, Solaceon Town in
>   Sinnoh, Route 3 in Unova and Route 7 in Kalos. Two Pokémon are
>   compatible if they are of the same species, or share at least one Egg
>   Group, and are of opposite genders (see below); alternatively,
>   breeding is usually still possible as long as one of them is Ditto,
>   even if the other parent is genderless. Legendary Pokémon (excluding
>   Phione and Manaphy), baby Pokémon, Unown, Nidorina and Nidoqueen
>   cannot breed whatsoever. **Pokémon with gender unknown (besides the
>   aforementioned Pokémon) can only breed with Ditto.**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, genderless Pokemon can only breed with Ditto and only if they are not in the Undiscovered egg group, which consists largely of Legendary Pokemon but also baby Pokemon and the Nidorina line.

Comment: So there is no reason to belong to some other group like Amorphus?

Comment: There is no reason other than "they don't really fit in any other group and we're not putting them in Undiscovered".